# How to solve this exception Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd, mutation, formik

I submitted the form using formik and added a mutation on button. Then, I got this exception below. How do I solve this exception?

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:25)
    at Object.error (QueryManager.js:154)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:134)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:165)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js:224)
    at Object.error (bundle.esm.js:74)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:134)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:165)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js:224)
    at bundle.esm.js:135
```

Here I add my sample code of formik form with mutation. I am adding mutation is correct way? How to add mutation of a form?

const { Form: AntForm, Row, Col, Button } = AntD;

```
    const POST_MUTATION = gql`
      mutation PostMutation($username: String!, $email: String!, 
     $password:String!){
        post(username: $username, email: $email, password: $password) {  
          username
          email
          password
        }
      }
    `
     class FormikApollo extends React.Component {
    
        state = {
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    
        render() {
            const { values, handleSubmit } = this.props
            const { username, email, password } = this.state
               return (
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Row gutter={4}>
                            <Col span={12} push={5}>
                                <Field
                                    name="username"
                                    label="Name"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Name"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    value={values.username}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout}
    
                                />
    
                                <Field
                                    name="email"
                                    label="Email"
                                    placeholder="Enter an Email"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    value={values.email}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout}
    
                                />      
                                <Mutation mutation={POST_MUTATION} 
                        variables={{ username, email, password }}>
                         {postMutation =>
                                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={postMutation}>Submit</Button>
                                    }
                         
                    </Form>
    
                </div>
    
            )
    
        }
    }
```

And my formik form is submitted by using handleSubmit with values

```
  const FormikApp = withFormik({
                    mapPropsToValues({ username, email, password }) {
                        return {
                            username: username || '',
                            email: email || '',
                            password: password || ''
                
                        }
                    },
                   
                    handleSubmit(values, { resetForm, props }) {
                        resetForm();
                        console.log(values)
                    }
                
                })(FormikApollo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error that is returning an HTML website instead of JSON. The `<` token the error is referring to is the start of `<html>` tag.

You can corroborate going to devtools, network tab, picking the one that fails and selecting sub tab 'response'.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same error when using **Apollo Client**:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://example.com/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

So, to solve the error, I put **a slash "/" to the end of the url in uri**:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://example.com/graphql/", // Here
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Then, I could solve the error.